# Dynamically copied signature gets truncated

Tags: python

I am trying to dynamically copy the signature of a function to another function (which is defined as a lambda):

```
from inspect import signature

def funcA(a: str) -> str:
    return a.lower()

funcB = lambda a: funcA(a)
funcB.__signature__ = signature(funcA)
help(funcB)
```

This *almost* works, except the resulting help signature is truncated at the start and end:

```
Help on function <lambda> in module __main__:

<lambda> lambda a: str) -> st
```

instead of the expected, `lambda a: str -> str`.

Comment: I guess `help` has some special handling around lambdas you're running into, it's trimmed the start too, but it's likely easier to use the existing `functools.wraps`: `funcB = wraps(funcA)(lambda a: funcA(a))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is special handling for lambdas, done deliberately (and acknowledged as unsafe) [by `pydoc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/pydoc.py#L1060-L1067):

```
            if signature:
                argspec = str(signature)
                if realname == '<lambda>':
                    title = '<strong>%s</strong> <em>lambda</em> ' % name
                    # XXX lambda's won't usually have func_annotations['return']
                    # since the syntax doesn't support but it is possible.
                    # So removing parentheses isn't truly safe.
                    argspec = argspec[1:-1] # remove parentheses
```

If you look at the signature for the lambda *before* you assign to its `__signature__`, you can see the parentheses this is intended to remove:

```
>>> str(signature(lambda a: funcA(a)))
'(a)'
```

The only way to avoid this would be to define `funcB` as a regular function, or to pad the signature to account for the trimming.